# UI-Router: Change part of the url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular's UI-router. All my routes looks like that:
/:name/....
for example /:name/test/:id, /:name/logs, /:name/list/:id

I want to change the name part when I click on a button, and reload the page. How can i do that globally without knowing exactly what route I'm in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$state.go($state.current, { name, 'newValue' });
```

Or something similar with ui-sref.